# query posts and split meta information into separate div's

Tags: post-meta, wp-list-pages

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of the content showcase/slider seen here:

http://stylewatch.stelladot.com/

From what I see in the HTML, it appears that there's 2 divs, one with the post images and one with the post titles.

I'd like to use something like `wp_list_pages` to return the 4 most recent posts and put them in the slider, but I'm not quite sure how to do it. It seems that they're in separate div's - how would I query the posts and split the set of images from the set of post names? I guess I could make 2 queries and have one query images while the other queries titles but it seems that isn't the most efficient way to do so.

EDIT: Adding sample desired markup - the content of `media-0` and `title-0` should be from the same post.

```
<div id="slider">

  <div id="slider-images">
    <div id="media-0">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div id="media-1">
      <img>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="slider-titles">
    <div id="title-0>
      <div class="title">text</div>
    </div>
    <div id="title-1">
      <div class="title">text</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have a difficult time doing that with `wp_list_pages()`. You will need to **create a custom query loop**, using either [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

## Custom loop with 4 most recent posts

```
<?php
$recent_posts_query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4
);
$recent_posts = new WP_Query( $recent_posts_query_args );

// Open custom loop
if ( $recent_posts->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $recent_posts->have_posts() ) : 
        $recent_posts->the_post();

        // Normal post template tags can be used here, just like constructing a normal loop

    // Close custom loop
    endwhile; 
endif;

// Be kind; reset postdata
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

The actual markup you use is up to you. The custom loop markup/output is like any other loop at this point.

Comment: Thanks Chip, that makes much more sense. The only thing I'm stuck on is, the loop takes a set of markup and iterates that for each post. In the example slider, they have 2 sets of meta data, each of which corresponds to the same post, but they are split into separate div's. Is that possible in the loop?

Comment: added markup example

Comment: The loop can take any manner of HTML or PHP markup. It doesn't care what you pass to it. :)